# How to correctly write async XUnit test?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, moq, xunit

I am using async xUnit tests and I am noticing inconsistent passing behavior:

```
public async Task FetchData()
{
    //Arrange
    var result = await arrangedService.FetchDataAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    //Assert
}
```

I have gone through the call stack executed by this test and have verified that all of my library code is calling `.ConfigureAwait(false)` after each task. However, in spite of this, this test and others will intermittently fail when performing a `Run All`, but pass the asserts and manual inspection when I walk through on the debugger. So clearly I am not doing something correctly. I have tried removing the call to `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the test itself in case there is a special xUnit synchronization context, but it did not change anything. What is the best way to test asynchronous code in a consistent way?

**EDIT** Okay here is my attempt to create a super-simplified example of the code that is running to provide an example of what is happening:

```
using Graph = Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;

public async Task FetchData()
{
    var adUsers = baseUsers //IEnumerable<Graph.User>
        .Cast<Graph.IUser>()
        .ToList();
    var nextPageUsers = Enumerable
        .Range(GoodIdMin, GoodIdMax)
        .Select(number => new Graph.User
        {
            Mail = (-number).ToString()
        })
        .Cast<Graph.IUser>()
        .ToList();

    var mockUserPages = new Mock<IPagedCollection<Graph.IUser>>();
    mockUserPages
        .Setup(pages => pages.MorePagesAvailable)
        .Returns(true);
    mockUserPages
        .Setup(pages => pages.CurrentPage)
        .Returns(new ReadOnlyCollection<Graph.IUser>(adUsers));
    mockUserPages
        .Setup(pages => pages.GetNextPageAsync())
        .ReturnsAsync(mockUserPages.Object)
        .Callback(() =>
        {
            mockUserPages
                .Setup(pages => pages.CurrentPage)
                .Returns(new ReadOnlyCollection<Graph.IUser>(nextPageUsers));
            mockUserPages
                .Setup(pages => pages.MorePagesAvailable)
                .Returns(false);
        });

    var mockUsers = new Mock<Graph.IUserCollection>();
    mockUsers
        .Setup(src => src.ExecuteAsync())
        .ReturnsAsync(mockUserPages.Object);

    var mockGraphClient = new Mock<Graph.IActiveDirectoryClient>();
    mockGraphClient
        .Setup(src => src.Users)
        .Returns(mockUsers.Object);

    var mockDbUsers = CreateBasicMockDbSet(baseUsers.Take(10)
        .Select(user => new User
        {
            Mail = user.Mail
        })
        .AsQueryable());
    var mockContext = new Mock<MyDbContext>();
    mockContext
        .Setup(context => context.Set<User>())
        .Returns(mockDbUsers.Object);

    var mockGraphProvider = new Mock<IGraphProvider>(); 
    mockGraphProvider
        .Setup(src => src.GetClient()) //Creates an IActiveDirectoryClient
        .Returns(mockGraphClient.Object);

    var getter = new UserGetter(mockContext.Object, mockGraphProvider.Object);

    var result = await getter.GetData().ConfigureAwait(false);

    Assert.True(result.Success); //Not the actual assert
}
```

And here is the code being executed on the `var result = ...` line:

```
public UserGetterResult GetData()
{
    var adUsers = await GetAdUsers().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var dbUsers = Context.Set<User>().ToList(); //This is the injected context from before
    return new UserGetterResult //Just a POCO
    {
        AdUsers = adUsers
            .Except(/*Expression that indicates whether
             or not this user is in the database*/)
            .ProjectTo<User>()
            .ToList(),
        DbUsers = dbUsers.ProjectTo<User>().ToList() //Automapper 6.1.1
    };
}

private async Task<List<User>> GetAdUsers()
{
    var userPages = await client //Injected IActiveDirectoryClient from before
        .Users
        .ExecuteAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    var users = userPages.CurrentPage.ToList();
    while(userPages.MorePagesAvailable)
    {
        userPages = await userPages.GetNextPageAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        users.AddRange(userPages.CurrentPage);
    }
    return users;
}
```

The purpose of the code is to get a list of users who are in AD but not the database and a list of users who are in the database.

**EDIT EDIT** Since I forgot to include this in the original update, the errors are all occurring on calls to `IUserCollection.ExecuteAsync().

Comment: If your test fails intermittently, then it's very likely a race condition somewhere. If you ever find a way to debug them consistently, you'll be considered as a hero by developers worldwide

Comment: @Nkosi Okay I have done my best to recreate this in its entirety.

Comment: @KevinGosse I doubt it is a race condition because all mocked services are contained within the scope of the test and even so they are using thread-safe read objects like List<T>.

Comment: Quick question, I assume the code under test works in production?

Comment: Sorry to reply late, the code has been working fine when manually tested through a typical use-case.

Comment: What is the error you get when it fails?

Answer (score 1):

`IUserCollection.ExecuteAsync()` appears to be configured correctly based on what was shown in the original post.

Now focusing on the following method...

```
private async Task<List<User>> GetAdUsers() {
    var userPages = await client //Injected IActiveDirectoryClient from before
        .Users
        .ExecuteAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    var users = userPages.CurrentPage.ToList();
    while(userPages.MorePagesAvailable) {
        userPages = await userPages.GetNextPageAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        users.AddRange(userPages.CurrentPage);
    }
    return users;
}
```

I am concerned with how user pages was setup in the mock. Given the flow of the `GetAdUsers` method it would be better to use `SetupSequence` to mock the repeated calls `CurrentPage` and `MorePagesAvailable`.

```
var mockUserPages = new Mock<IPagedCollection<Graph.IUser>>();
mockUserPages
    .SetupSequence(_ => _.MorePagesAvailable)
    .Returns(true) // First time called to enter while loop
    .Returns(false); // Second time called to exit while loop
mockUserPages
    .SetupSequence(_ => _.CurrentPage)
    .Returns(new ReadOnlyCollection<Graph.IUser>(adUsers)) // First time called to get List
    .Returns(new ReadOnlyCollection<Graph.IUser>(nextPageUsers)); // Second time called to get next page
mockUserPages
    .Setup(pages => pages.GetNextPageAsync())
    .ReturnsAsync(mockUserPages.Object); // No need for callback
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem could be the delay between executing the callback and next request to mockUserPages.CurrentPage

Try separating the User page collection:

```
var mockAdUserPages = new Mock<IPagedCollection<Graph.IUser>>();
    mockAdUserPages 
        .Setup(pages => pages.MorePagesAvailable)
        .Returns(true);
    mockAdUserPages 
        .Setup(pages => pages.CurrentPage)
        .Returns(new ReadOnlyCollection<Graph.IUser>(adUsers));

//Setup second page
var mockNextUserPages = new Mock<IPagedCollection<Graph.IUser>>();
mockNextUserPages 
        .Setup(pages => pages.MorePagesAvailable)
        .Returns(false);
    mockNextUserPages 
        .Setup(pages => pages.CurrentPage)
        .Returns(new ReadOnlyCollection<Graph.IUser>(nextPageUsers));

//Return next page
    mockAdUserPages 
        .Setup(pages => pages.GetNextPageAsync())
        .ReturnsAsync(mockNextUserPages.Object);
```

Comment: No, last setup overrides any previous setup.

Comment: Even when doing this, this test and some others without the callback() intermittently fail.